# Alternative to transaction lock and process parallel requests from different users

Tags: java, race-condition

I have a condition where only a particular number of create operation for an entity is allowed. To avoid race condition i have used transaction locks. But at the same time i want to process parallel requests from different users.
Is there any way in java where parallel requests from different users can be processed without any race condition?

Comment: Could you please add more details or create [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what should be enhanced.

Comment: @geobreeze, atleast for me the question is quite clear

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem is:

1. *There is an API which has a 'create' operation. This creates a single item unless it is not allowed.*
2. *For each user there is a limit; they must not be allowed to create more than 5 items.*

And you want to ensure that somebody invoking the 'create' API two times, concurrently, won't allow you to sneak in a have a single user end up making 6 items.

Of course you can do that.

There are 2 broad strategies you can use.

### Have self-guarded collections

It's not clear where these entities are stored or otherwise tracked. Let's say that the *create* API simply adds a object to an ArrayList someplace.

Then do not use an arraylist but use a *bounded queue*, such as BlockingQueue.

But, perhaps what's happening is not a thing that can easily be modified like this.

### Lock per user

Have a store that stores 1 lock for each user in the system; this can be a dynamic system, where the lock object itself ends up disappearing once it hits 0.

Something like:

```
class LockStore {
    private final Map<Long, Lock> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Lock>();

    public Lock getLock(long userId) {
        return map.computeIfAbsent(userId, userId -> new ReentrantLock());
    }
}
```

If the # of users in the system can be excessively large it needs to be made more complicated, where locks whose lock count drops to 0 end up getting removed from the map. That removal itself requires some smart usage of concurrent methods to ensure that doesn't itself cause race conditions.